# Homestead PHP Version Wrong

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I am trying to make a vagrant homestead server for Laravel 5.4.36. So that I can practice upgrading my main website to the latest laravel version locally.

The server starts up correctly, but I am expecting/need PHP version 7.0. Instead I get version 7.2.3 when I type "php --version" in the SSH terminal. The documentation says that homestead 5.2.0 SHOULD install PHP version 7.0, but it's not. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead)

Typing "php artisan --version" returns the expected 5.4.36 laravel version...

Thoughts on how I can fix this? Is it possible to downgrade php versions and specify 7.0?

Here is my Homestead.yaml file...

```
ip: 192.168.10.10
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox
authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
version: 5.2.0
keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa
folders:
    -
        map: 'C:\Users\Rick\Desktop\MyWebsite'
        to: /home/vagrant/code
sites:
    -
        map: mywebsite.test
        to: /home/vagrant/code/public
    -
        map: sub.mywebsite.test
        to: /home/vagrant/code/public
databases:
    - homestead
    - mywebsite
features:
    -
        mariadb: false
    -
        ohmyzsh: false
    -
        webdriver: false
name: mywebsite
hostname: www.mywebsite.test
```

Comment: What's your purpose on this? I'm pretty sure there are no benefits from downgrading from 7.2 to 7.0

Comment: My live website is running on php version 7.0.33... I'd like to have an identical environment so I can try upgrading locally and address any issues before doing so on a live environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Homestead has several versions of PHP. If you view `~/.bash_aliases`, you should see several lines like this:

```
function php70() {
    sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.0
    sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.0
    sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.0
}

function php71() {
    sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.1
    sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.1
    sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.1
}

function php72() {
    sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
    sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.2
    sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.2
}

function php73() {
    sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.3
    sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.3
    sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.3
}
```

Type `php70` on the command line, and it will switch the command-line versions.

For the web versions, you'll need to either update the nginx config file manually or add the PHP version to the mapping:

```
 map: mywebsite.test
 to: /home/vagrant/code/public
 php: "7.0"
```

You'll have to destroy the box and restart it to get it to reload the Homestead file.

Comment: Oh thank you! The web version was 7.0, the CLI was 7.2... Wasn't aware there was a difference in version... phpinfo() showed me the correct version...

Comment: Thank you, this was the workaround for this error I was getting: php 73
Could not open input file: 73

Comment: @SpencerHill There's no space in the command. `php73`, not `php 73`

Answer (score 1):

Using the latest Homestead, you may do the following:

In your `Homestead.yaml`, you may specify a PHP version to each site.

```
  sites:
    -
        map: mywebsite.test
        to: /home/vagrant/code/public
        php: "7.1"
    -
        map: sub.mywebsite.test
        to: /home/vagrant/code/public
        php: "8.0"
```

If that doesn't work, you may also change the default version of PHP used by the CLI by issuing any of the following commands from within your Homestead virtual machine:

```
php56
php70
php71
php72
php73
php74
php80
```

Eg. Type `php71` in your command line to change the Homestead PHP version to PHP 7.1

This will change your Homestead environment according to the PHP version you specify.
You may refer to the [Official Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#php-versions) for more information.